# Combining UNPIVOT with other select statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've created a Table-valued function in SQL server called dba.pp_Datasource_IL1201_Auto_Vehicles. The resulting dynamic data is going to flow to a PDF form. When I just query the second select that has the UNPIVOT operator, the data flows perfectly fine to the PDF and displays as desired in SSMS. However, when I add other columns, I get this error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

DESIRED RESULT:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| DATA 1 | UNPIV DATA |
| NULL | UNPIV DATA |
| NULL | UNPIV DATA |
| NULL | UNPIV DATA |
| NULL | UNPIV DATA |
| NULL | UNPIV DATA |
| NULL | UNPIV DATA |
| NULL | UNPIV DATA |
| NULL | UNPIV DATA |
| NULL | UNPIV DATA |

```
SELECT book_veh_num,
(select description

        FROM
            (
             SELECT
            convert(varchar(255), veh_status) as veh_status,
            convert(varchar(255), veh_num) as veh_num,
            convert(varchar(255), veh_year) as veh_year,
            convert(varchar(255), veh_make) as veh_make,
            convert(varchar(255), veh_model) as veh_model,
            convert(varchar(255), veh_vin) as veh_vin,
            convert(varchar(255), veh_cost_new) as veh_cost_new,
            convert(varchar(255), veh_garage_loc) as veh_garage_loc,
            convert(varchar(255), veh_class_code) as veh_class_code,
            convert(varchar(255), ' ') as blank_line
             FROM dba.pp_Datasource_IL1201_Auto_Vehicles(8589100, 'BusAuto')
            ) d
UNPIVOT
( description for vehicle in
(veh_status, veh_num, veh_year, veh_make, veh_model, veh_vin, veh_cost_new, veh_garage_loc, veh_class_code, blank_line)
) unpiv)

FROM dba.pp_Datasource_IL1201_Auto_Vehicles(8589100, 'BusAuto')
```

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. Your second (unaliased) column will return *multiple* rows and that isn't allowed. Why do you want to unpivot inside a column's definition.

Comment: I need to UNPIVOT to accommodate the way the data needs to display on the pdf form it's going to. Is there any way to make my scenario happen?

Comment: can't you just write this without the subquery

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I need the subquery to UNPIVOT

Comment: No you don't; you *can't* unpivot in a subquery in the `SELECT`. Perhaps you want a derived table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you've used a subquery, rather than derived table. This is impossible to test, as we have no sample data, but perhaps this is what you want:

```sql
SELECT description, vehicle
FROM (SELECT CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_status) AS veh_status,
             CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_num) AS veh_num,
             CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_year) AS veh_year,
             CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_make) AS veh_make,
             CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_model) AS veh_model,
             CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_vin) AS veh_vin,
             CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_cost_new) AS veh_cost_new,
             CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_garage_loc) AS veh_garage_loc,
             CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_class_code) AS veh_class_code,
             CONVERT(varchar(255), ' ') AS blank_line
      FROM dba.pp_Datasource_IL1201_Auto_Vehicles(8589100, 'BusAuto') ) d
    UNPIVOT (description
             FOR vehicle IN (veh_status, veh_num, veh_year, veh_make, veh_model, veh_vin, veh_cost_new, veh_garage_loc, veh_class_code, blank_line)) unpiv;
```

Alternatively, you could unpivot your data with a `VALUES` table construct:

```sql
SELECT V.ColumnValue,
       V.ColumnName
FROM dba.pp_Datasource_IL1201_Auto_Vehicles(8589100,N'BusAuto')DIAV
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_status),N'veh_status'),
                        (CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_num),N'veh_num'),
                        (CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_year),N'veh_year'),
                        (CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_make),N'veh_make'),
                        (CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_model),N'veh_model'),
                        (CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_vin),N'veh_vin'),
                        (CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_cost_new),N'veh_cost_new'),
                        (CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_garage_loc),N'veh_garage_loc'),
                        (CONVERT(varchar(255), veh_class_code),N'veh_class_code'),
                        (CONVERT(varchar(255), ' '),N'blank_line'))V(ColumnValue,ColumnName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample pivot query with some data. I'm guessing you're doing correlated subquery to get casts correct, but you can instead prepare everything in a subquery:

```sql
drop table #car


create table #car (vin int, make varchar(30), color varchar(30), cost int)

insert into #car (vin, make, color, cost)
select 1234, 'BMW', 'Red', 99999
union
select 1235, 'Mercedes', 'Blue', 100000
union
select 1236, 'Volvo', 'Silver arrow', 3000

select vin, vehicle, description
from (
    select vin, make, color, cast(cost as varchar(30)) AS cost
    from #car
    ) x
unpivot (description for vehicle in (make, color, cost)) v
```